# access to SeismicCube from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, ocean, petrel

i'm using thread to launch on background a function using `SeismicCube`

```
public class JobSetup
{
    public SeismicCube cube;
}

public void Function1(SeismicCube cube)
{    
    var jobSetup = new JobSetup();
    jobSetup.cube = cube;
    var th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadFunc));
    th.Start(jobSetup); 
}     

public void ThreadFunc(object state)
{
    var jobSetup = (JobSetup)state;
    ...
    ...
    Point3 new_p = jobSetup.cube.PositionAtIndex(new IndexDouble3(y, x, z));
}
```

Because Petrel is a single-threaded application, all access to native Petrel domain objects must take place on the main thread. Otherwise, you receive this run-time error:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled Message=”Cross-thread operation not valid: 
>   Application accessed domain object from a thread other than the main thread.” Source=”Slb.Ocean.Petrel.DomainObject”